# Can't get ID of the next php generated row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to generate some text boxes after each line of row sent from database, so I have this user who have 2 rows:

[image]

And of course each row belongs to an `id`:

```
                      <td><?php echo $counter--; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $installment['date_now'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $installment['payment'] ?> $</td></tr>

                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <tr><th colspan="10" style="text-align: right;">Remaining:</th>
                    <th><?php echo  ($cash['project_cost'] - $sum) ?> $</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="<?php echo $cash['infoid']; ?>"><td colspan="8" style="text-align: right;">Add Payment</td>
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_pay_now[]"/></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="pay_now"/></td>
                    <td><button id="add_payment" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
                  </tr>
                  <tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>
                <?php $sumCash = $sumCash + $cash['project_cost']; } ?>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="10">Cash Total</th><th id="final_cash"><?php echo $sumCash ?> $</th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
              <?php } else { ?>
              No Payments available
            <?php } ?>
```

Now, when select a date and type an amount, I should send those values into `AJAX` and but first I need to get the `id` of the row so I can send it too.

```
$("#add_payment").click(function()
{
  var date_of_pay = $("#date_pay_now").val();
  var pay_now = $("#pay_now").val();
  var id_pay = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  console.log(id_pay);
  if(date_of_pay == "" || pay_now == "")
  {
    $("#date_pay_now").css('border-color', 'red');
    $("#pay_now").css('border-color', 'red');
  }
  if(date_of_pay != "" && pay_now != "")
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      //Still not typed
    });
  }
});
```

If you see the image, when I click on the first button, I see the id correctly at the console and if they are empty I can see the red color, but when I refresh the page and click directly on the second row button, I can't see any value at the console and no css color due to empty text box shown.

[image]

And here when I click on the next button, no color and no id at the console:

[image]

Comment: `$("#add_payment")` must reffer to an unique element in the dom. I suppose that you have one button per row, so you should select them with a class selector rather than an ID. Anyway, when attaching events to elements. You should insure that the elements exist in the page. There are plenty of subject in SO on how to dynamically attach event handler. One hint : `$('document').on('click', 'myButtons', function() {... });`

Comment: so How can I fix the code using `.on` ?

Comment: I added `.on('click', '#add_payment', function(){` and now it works. How ? Why without `.on` it didn't worked ? I hope you can explain it to me easily

Comment: But still only the first text box change color though

Comment: The color is an other issue. Again, you should only use unique IDs. Why `.on` works ? Because it tells your document to attach a click event handler to anything matching the condition and the condition is evaluated 'on' click. If you use classic `.click()` it will look for the selected items and attach them the handler. Any object added later in the document are brand new and don't have event handler attached to them. The event handler attached to the document with `.on` is allways here, non alterred...

Comment: so you recommend to always work with `.on()` instead of `.click()` or `.change()` or ... ? Now please help me with the color issue

Comment: No, I don't recommand anything on this subject. You just have to know that there is a difference. But if you are working with dynamically created objects, you must use `.on`. Now for the color. `$('#date_pay_now')` means : Go find the unique item that has the ID 'date_pay_now'. It finds the first one so on ly the first one is concerned here. That's why you must not use non-unique ID